# Query .dbf files in .net core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oledb, oledbconnection, dbf

I've been tasked with re-writing an old winforms app so that it works in `.net core 3`. I've ran into a brick wall where the original app uses `OleDB` to query some large `.dbf` files, and there's no equivalent in `.net core`. Has anybody had to do similar? If so what was the best approach?

I'm stuck with the .dbf files unfortunately as these are created by a 3rd party application (That I think was created using VF Pro many many many moons ago??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem some time ago, needing to read DBase files and finding no C# support. I ended up writing the [DBase.NET](https://github.com/henck/dBASE.NET) (GitHub) library - it may help you out.

Comment: Looking at the repo - it should be simple enough to port over to .net core. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research, `oledb` library has been ported over to .net core 3.0+...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=netframework-4.8

However it looks like it's still not completely stable when dealing with VF Pro judging from this git thread:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/981

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [DbfDataReader](https://github.com/yellowfeather/DbfDataReader)